# Using ParserResult

Tags: f#, fparsec

The example code below appears to work nicely:

```
open FParsec
let capitalized : Parser<unit,unit> =(asciiUpper >>. many asciiLower >>. eof)
let inverted : Parser<unit,unit> =(asciiLower >>. many asciiUpper >>. eof)
let capsOrInvert =choice [capitalized;inverted]
```

You can then do:

```
run capsOrInvert "Dog";;
run capsOrInvert "dOG";;
```

and get a success or:

```
run capsOrInvert "dog";;
```

and get a failure.

Now that I have a ParserResult, how do I do things with it? For example, print the string backwards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several notable issues with your code.

First off, as noticed in @scrwtp's answer, **your parser returns `unit`.** Here's why: operator `(>>.)` returns only the result returned by the *right* inner parser. On the other hand, `(.>>)` would return the result of a *left* parser, while `(.>>.)` would return a tuple of both *left* and *right* ones.

So, `parser1 >>. parser2 >>. eof` is essentially `(parser1 >>. parser2) >>. eof`.
The code in parens completely ignores the result of `parser1`, and the second `(>>.)` then ignores the entire result of the parser in parens. Finally, `eof` returns `unit`, and this value is being returned.

You may need some **meaningful data returned** instead, e.g. the parsed string. The easiest way is:

```
let capitalized = (asciiUpper .>>. many asciiLower .>> eof)
```

Mind the operators.
The code for `inverted` can be done in a similar manner.

---

This parser would be of type `Parser<(char * char list), unit>`, a tuple of first character and all the remaining ones, so you may need to **merge them back**. There are several ways to do that, here's one:

```
let mymerge (c1: char, cs: char list) = c1 :: cs // a simple cons
let pCapitalized = capitalized >>= mymerge
```

The beauty of this code is that your **`mymerge` is a normal function**, working with normal `char`'s, it knows nothing about parsers or so. It just works with the data, and `(>>=)` operator does the rest.

Note, `pCapitalized` is also a parser, but it returns a single `char list`.

---

Nothing stops you from **applying further transitions**. As you mentioned printing the string backwards:

```
let pCapitalizedAndReversed =
    capitalized
    >>= mymerge
    >>= List.rev
```

I have written the code in this way for purpose. In different lines you see *a gradual transition of your domain data*, **still within the paradigm of Parser**. This is an important consideration, because any subsequent transition may "decide" that the data is bad for some reason and raise a parsing exception, for example. Or, alternatively, it may be merged with other parser.

As soon as your domain data (a parsed-out word) is complete, you extract the result as mentioned in another answer.

---

A minor note. `choice` is superfluous for only two parsers. Use `(<|>)` instead. From experience, careful choosing parser combinators is important because a wrong choice deep inside your core parser logic can easily make your parsers dramatically slow.
See [FParsec Primitives](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members) for further details.

Answer (score 8):

`ParserResult` is a discriminated union. You simply match the `Success` and `Failure` cases.

```
let r = run capsOrInvert "Dog"

match r with
| Success(result, _, _)   -> printfn "Success: %A" result
| Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" errorMsg
```

But this is probably not what you find tricky about your situation.

The thing about your `Parser<unit, unit>` type is that the parsed value is of type `unit` (the first type argument to `Parser`). What this means is that this parser doesn't really produce any sensible output for you to use - it can only tell you whether it can parse a string (in which case you get back a `Success ((), _, _)` - carrying the single value of type `unit`) or not.

What do you expect to get out of this parser?

**Edit**: This sounds close to what you want, or at least you should be able to pick up some pointers from it. `capitalized` accepts capitalized strings, `inverted` accepts capitalized strings that have been reversed and reverses them as part of the parser logic.

```
let reverse (s: string) = 
    System.String(Array.rev (Array.ofSeq s))

let capitalized : Parser<string,unit> = 
    (asciiUpper .>>. manyChars asciiLower)  
    |>> fun (upper, lower) -> string upper + lower

let inverted : Parser<string,unit> = 
    (manyChars asciiLower .>>. asciiUpper)
    |>> fun (lower, upper) -> reverse (lower + string upper)

let capsOrInvert = choice [capitalized;inverted]

run capsOrInvert "Dog"
run capsOrInvert "doG"
run capsOrInvert "dog"
```

Comment: I was hoping to get the parsed string back. How would I modify it to do that? Really, I'm just getting started with this lib. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You'd usually want some more structured data representation coming out of a parser rather than going from a string to a string, but fair enough. I've added something that sounds close to what you want, the other answer also has some informative examples.